# Is it possible to multiply a string to an integer using numpy multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to element-wise multiply two arrays to form a single string.

Can anyone advise?

```
import numpy as np


def array_translate(array):

    intlist = [x for x in array if isinstance(x, int)]
    strlist = [x for x in array if isinstance(x, str)]
    joinedlist = np.multiply(intlist, strlist)
    return "".join(joinedlist)


print(array_translate(["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1]))    # => "CatCatDogDogDogMouse"
```

I receive this error:

```
File "/Users/peteryoon/PycharmProjects/Test3/Test3.py", line 8, in array_translate
    joinedlist = np.multiply(intlist, strlist)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

I was able to solve using list comprehension below. But curious to see how numpy works.

```
def array_translate(array):

    intlist = [x for x in array if isinstance(x, int)]
    strlist = [x for x in array if isinstance(x, str)]
    return "".join(intlist*strlist for intlist, strlist in zip(intlist, strlist))


print(array_translate(["Cat", 2, "Dog", 3, "Mouse", 1]))    # => "CatCatDogDogDogMouse"
```

Comment: String multiply as repeat is a python string definition. `numpy` has not defined it for its string dtype.  If lists and strings do the job, don't put a lot of effort into finding a numpy equivalent.  It rarely is faster or easier.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [79]: arr = np.array(['Cat','Dog','Mouse'])                                  
In [80]: cnt = np.array([2,3,1])
```

Timings for various alternatives.  The relative placement may vary with the size of the arrays (and whether you start with lists or arrays).  So do your own testing:

```
In [93]: timeit ''.join(np.repeat(arr,cnt))                                     
7.98 µs ± 57.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [94]: timeit ''.join([str(wd)*i for wd,i in zip(arr,cnt)])                   
5.96 µs ± 167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [95]: timeit ''.join(arr.astype(object)*cnt)                                 
13.3 µs ± 50.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [96]: timeit ''.join(np.char.multiply(arr,cnt))                              
27.4 µs ± 307 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [100]: timeit ''.join(np.frompyfunc(lambda w,i: w*i,2,1)(arr,cnt))           
10.4 µs ± 164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [101]: %%timeit f = np.frompyfunc(lambda w,i: w*i,2,1) 
     ...: ''.join(f(arr,cnt))                                                                       
7.95 µs ± 93.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [102]: %%timeit x=arr.tolist(); y=cnt.tolist() 
     ...: ''.join([str(wd)*i for wd,i in zip(x,y)])                                                                      
1.36 µs ± 39.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`np.repeat` works for all kinds of arrays.

List comprehension uses the string multiply, and shouldn't be dismissed out of hand.  Often it is fastest, especially if starting with lists.

Object dtype converts the string dtype to Python strings, and then delegates the action to the string multiply.

`np.char` applies string methods to elements of an array.  While convenient, it seldom is fast.

### edit

```
In [104]: timeit ''.join(np.repeat(arr,cnt).tolist())                           
4.04 µs ± 197 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: For me `"".join(arr.repeat(cnt).tolist())` is much faster than `"".join(np.repeat(arr,cnt))`. With those small examples the overheads of the function to method dispatch and of the slow numpy getitem/array iteration are significant. In my experience a `.tolist()` before explicit or implicit Python looping almost always pays for itself.

Comment: Good point, `join` expects an iterable, and `arr.tolist()` is better than `list(arr)`

Answer (score 3):

perhaps using repeat

```
z = array(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse'], dtype='<U5')
"".join(np.repeat(z, (2, 3, 1)))
'CatCatDogDogDogMouse'
```